# bootstrap3 datepicker working, but not passing POST variables in form

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I have been working with the datepicker plugin located here - http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/  and the actual datepicker works, it adds dates into the boxes visually.

But the two variables ( a "from" date and a "to" date) are not passing through as POST variables when the form is submitted. Can anybody help me see where I went wrong?

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dtp_input1" class="col-md-2 control-label">FROM:   </label>
            <div class="input-group date form_date col-md-5" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input1" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" /><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dtp_input2" class="col-md-2 control-label">TO:</label>
            <div class="input-group date form_date col-md-5" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" /><br/>
        </div>

  <!-- Text input-->

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-8 text-right">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" formaction="dates.php" formmethod="POST"></button>
 </div>
 </div></fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: How are you accessing the values on server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the input dtp_input1/dtp_input2 a name attribute?

```
<input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" name="from" /> 
<input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" name="to" /> 

$_POST['from'] 
$_POST['to']
```

Does that help?

Comment: thank you Bert that was the part I was lacking! It works perfectly now!